# Resources can not be found after build in unity

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, plugins

I'm trying to create a plugin for Android. I wrote Android code with Eclipse and created `.jar` file and I put `.jar` file and libraries in the Android folder in plugins and I wrote my code in Unity to start activity in Android.

My code works fine in Eclipse but when I build my project in Unity and run it I get this error in start activity:

```js
 10-12 18:51:31.956: W/ResourceType(3042): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
    10-12 18:51:31.956: W/System.err(3042): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
 10-12 18:51:31.956: D/StatusBar.MSimNetworkController(1192): refreshViews connected={ wifi } phoneId = 0 level=4 mMSimcombinedSignalIconId=0x7f0202f8/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_wifi_signal_4 mMSimcombinedActivityIconId=0x7f0202cb mAirplaneMode=false mMSimDataActivity=0 mMSimPhoneSignalIconId=0x7f0202c1/com.android.systemui:drawable/stat_sys_signal_dark_4_auto_rotate mMSimDataDirectionIconId=0x0 mMSimDataSignalIconId=0x7f0202c1 mMSimDataTypeIconId=0x0/(null) mNoMSimIconId=0x0/(null) mMSimMobileActivityIconId=0x0/(null) mWifiIconId=0x7f0202f8 mBluetoothTetherIconId=0x7f0202d5 mRoamingIconId=0x 0/(null) mSimEnabled=true
 10-12 18:51:31.956: D/STATUSBAR-WifiQuickSettingButton(1192): onWifiSignalChanged enabled=true enabledDesc:"NG"
 10-12 18:51:31.956: W/System.err(3042):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1542)
 10-12 18:51:31.956: W/System.err(3042):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1457)
 10-12 18:51:31.956: W/System.err(3042):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1434)
​
```

After I saw my apk I couldn't find raw folder and res files that I entered in Unity, my project files in unity showed in image:

[image]

res folder after build:

[image]

res folder exist in unity editor but not exist in apk file. How can I make res and raw folder be build?

Answer (score 0):

notice that .jar just include java code(other word .java file),you should search for "how to put resource into .jar"

i think its time to use android studio , in that ide , .aar package is more convenient than .jar because of including resource file

Comment: thank you but I have recourses in unity package but after build all of my resources is missing , im new in android and it is my first plugin , should I add any code to make unity build resources?